# Android Camera API exposureTargetOffset value

Tags: android, android-camera2, exposure

Would anyone know where I can find the `exposureTargetOffset` in Android Camera2 API?

iOS developers has this [property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624630-exposuretargetoffset?language=objc#declarations), but I cannot find it in Android. May be someone know how I can calculate it from current exposure value?

Comment: Did you get it ? I need this API as well .

Comment: I need to find it for camera2 api as well

Comment: probably you may find your solution here, have a look:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest

Comment: It seems, Android SDK doesn't provide any solution to find this value